# Invariant Subspace and orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

I found the following question:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space over $C$ and let $T$ in $A(V)$ be unitary transformation. Prove that if $U$ is a subset of $V$ and it is $T$-Invariant then also the orthogonal complement of $U$ is $T$-Invariant.

What does the set $A(V)$ means?

I tried to do the following:
Let $x$ be in the orthogonal complement of $U$, we need to show that for every y in $U$
$(T(x),y) = 0$.
If $T = T^*$ then $(T(x),y) = (x,T^*(y)) = (x,T(y)) = 0$ 
but in this case $T^* = T-1$ so $(T(x),y) = (x,T-1(y))$ but I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: I guess $\,A(V)\;$ is the set of all endomorphisms = all linear operators of $\,V\,$ to itself. BTW, you made almost all to prove what you want...

Answer (score 4):

No idea what $A(V)$ means, but if $U$ is $T$-invariant (i.e. $T(u) \in U$ for all $u \in U$), then $U^{\top} = \{ w \in V \, | \, \forall u \in U, \quad (w,u) = 0 \}$ will also be $T$-invariant.

Since $T$ is unitary, there exists $S$ such that $T \circ S$ is the identity map on $V$, so that $T$ is an isomorphism of $V$ to itself. By $T$-invariance, the restriction of $T$ to $U$ is an isomorphism of $U$ to itself, because $T$ maps $U$ to $U$ and is injective, but being a linear map of finite-dimensional vector spaces it must also be surjective.

This being said, if you take $w \in U^{\top}$ and an arbitrary element of $U$, write it in the form $u = T(u')$, then $T(w)$ is also in $U^{\top}$ because $(T(w), T(u')) = (w,u') = 0$. Since $u = T(u')$ was arbitrary, we conclude $T(w) \in U^{\top}$ and $U^{\top}$ is $T$-invariant.

Hope that helps,

Comment: How does the equality $\langle T(w), T(u') \rangle = \langle w, u \rangle$ follow? Also on the right-hand side there's a typo in your post: $u'$ should be $u$.

Comment: @Mussé Redi : There are different definitions of unitary which are all equivalent, and this is one of them. What is yours? By the way, I don't know of which right-hand side you are speaking of, but I read all my equations with a $u'$ in them and didn't see a typo. Maybe you understood me wrong somewhere?

Comment: My definition of unitary is the same as yours; I forgot. I see now why $u'$ is not a typo.

Comment: @Mussé Redi: don't try to be funny! I was serious, I don't see typos.

Comment: I thought it was a typo because I presumed you used $u=T(u')$ instead of the unitarity.

Comment: @Mussé Redi : I see! Indeed, all I used in that equation was the fact that $T$ was unitary. If you are used to the definition with $T^{\dagger}$, note that $T^{-1}=T^{\dagger}$, so you see that $u' = T^{\dagger}(u)$!

Comment: Why is the elaboration on the isomorficity of $T_U$ necessary; doesn't the result already follow from the $U$-invariance of $T$?

Comment: @Mussé Redi: I was proving to the OP that if $T$ is unitary and $U$ is $T$-invariant, then $T|_U$ is an automorphism of $U$. If you know this already, then of course it is not necessary! This allows me to find $u'$, which is possible by the surjectivity of $T|_U : U -> U$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva can you figure out some application of the fact that we have both subspace and its orthogonal compliment are invariant?

Comment: @MeetPatel The typical reason for the study of invariant subspaces is a decomposition. If you have a unitary transformation T on a vector space V, you can look at a decomposition of V into pairwise orthogonal subspaces which are all invariant under T. 

Examples of such a decomposition are for instance, the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition. Over the complex numbers, it takes a transformation T and writes it as T = D + N where D is diagonal and N is nilpotent. Digging in the details of the proof, you get the Jordan blocks. Each block corresponds to a T-invariant subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

We're given that

$$\forall\,u\in U\;,\;\;Tu\in U$$

Take now **any** $\;w\in U^\perp\;$ , and let us denote by $\;\langle,\rangle\;$ the inner product in $\,V\,$ , so:

$$\forall\,u\in U\;,\;\;0=\langle Tu,w\rangle=\langle u,T^*w\rangle\implies T^*w\in U^\perp$$

since it was **any** $\,u\in U\;,\;w\in U^\perp\;$ , and this means $\,T^*U^\perp\subset U^\perp\;$

Comment: He want to show $U^\perp$ is $T$-invariant, not $T^*$-invariant.

Comment: @OwenSizemore, it's the same in this case...right?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry if it seems trivial, but what makes them the same is what I was looking for.   Please help me.